# how to split string and int values

Tags: c++, file-handling, getline

I have this type of file and i read line until every `;`

For example from this line:

```
[
Armenia >> Azerbaijan: 787 km; Georgia: 164 km; Iran: 35 km; Turkey: 268 km; Nagorno-Karabakh Republic;
]

Armenia >> Azerbaijan: 787 km;  then  Georgia: 164 km; upto Nagorno-Karabakh Republic;
```

How can I split the string? i.e.: Armenia and Azerbaijan and the int value  i.e 787

[SCREENSHOT OF FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWm9K.png)

Comment: split what string? Do you have code to read from the file? Please include it in the question (see also [mcve])

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text

Comment: `std::string line; std::getline(filein, line, ';')`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the text already in a `std::string` variable, you can use the `find` method and the `substr` methods to extract text:

```
std::string text; // Text line read from file.
std::string::size_type position = text.find(" >> ");
std::string country;
std::string city;
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
  country = text.substr(1, position - 1);
  // Skip over " >> ";
  position += 4;
  std::string::size_type  position2 = text.find(";", position);
  if (position2 != std::string::npos)
  {
    city = text.substr(position, position2 - position);
  }
}
```

You can also use `find_first_not_of()` to skip over whitespace and extract the number.  Next, there are many methods to convert text representation of number to internal representation (such as `stoi`).

There are more possibilities, I've only shown one.